# Discord Bot Won't reply to commands

Tags: python, discord

Sorry to ask this question, people have asked this before but none of the solutions are working for me. everything else in my code works, my bot replies to if and elif statements, but when I try to add a command by prefix, I get: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Here is my code:

```
from imaplib import Commands
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from easy_pil import Editor, load_image_async, Font
from discord import File


intent = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(command_prefix=';', intents=intent)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')


@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if reason == None:
        reason = 'no reason given'
    await ctx.guild.kick(member)
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been kicked for {reason}')enter code here
```

'''

thanks for any help!

Comment: What solutions have you tried? What were the results (exceptions, wrong output, etc)? If you could edit your question with more details, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Solved it! thank you though!